# How to wrap HttpClient for testability in C#

Tags: httpclient, asp.net-web-api

I'm calling an external API and would like my API to be unit testable. And to do that, i'm trying to wrap HttpClient. I only need one method for now.
Here is my interface.

```
public interface IHttpClient
{
    Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url);
}
```

And this is how I implemented it.

public class HttpClientWrapper : IHttpClient
   {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

```
    public HttpClientWrapper()
    {
        // I could also inject this but I think this will be fine as is. 
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler(), false);
    }

    public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url)
    {
        //validate url here
        return await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    }
```

}

Doubts I have? is this the right way to do it? Will setting the bool parameter result in resource leaking here? I read a couple of conflicting ideas about whether HttpClient has to be disposed on every call or not. I took, the not disposing side but am not really quite certain though.
If there is a way to use HttpClient without having a wrapper but make the API testable, that will be great too. But so far, i failed to get that working.

Thanks,
CleanKoder

Answer (score 6):

While it could still be nice to create an interface for the client, the `HttpClient` class is actually designed with testability in mind! When instantiating your `HttpClient` you can inject a custom `HttpMessageHandler`. By overriding `Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` in this class, you can interrupt all requests before they are actually written to the socket, inspecting them and returning whatever you see fit.

Here is an example of such a test double I wrote in a project, feel free to modify it to suit your needs:

```
public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    public HttpRequestMessage LastRequest;
    public string LastRequestString = string.Empty;
    public string ResponseContent = string.Empty;
    public HttpStatusCode ResponseStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            LastRequestString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        LastRequest = request;
        return await Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = ResponseStatusCode,
            Content = new StringContent(ResponseContent)
        });
    }
}
```

You could also use some isolation framework like NSubstitute if you think that's more appropriate for your project.

Comment: What do you pass in real code? HttpMessageHandler is abstract.

Comment: I don't know if it's what is used in the default constructor, but after a quick search I would assume https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler(v=vs.118).aspx